# All my PHP files are prompting direct download

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What causes PHP pages to consistently download instead of running normally](https://serverfault.com/questions/215455/what-causes-php-pages-to-consistently-download-instead-of-running-normally)

All php files on my website are prompting direct download instead of viewing the page.

So for example: going to  mydomain.com/index.php  in browser will direct download the index.php file.

All my files are completely naked to the public.

I'm not sure how this happened, how can i trouble shoot this?

I am using linux, centos, with cPanel. My htaccess file is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have the php module loaded for Apache :

Try the following command

```
apachectl -M
```

In the output you should see

```
 php5_module (shared)
```

If you don't:
1. make sure php is installed
2. It is enabled in the Apache configuration files:

```
more /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>

AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Since you are using CPanel you should be able to enable for your server through the CPanel configuration options.